# Form onsubmit return fails after xmlhttp.open

Tags: javascript, return-value, form-submit, xmlhttprequest

My form adds a line to a database. What I am trying to do is to check if my data is already in it, and make me confirm if the new data shall be added.

Form:

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return check();">
<input type="text" name="lok" placeholder="lokalitet" value="">
<input type="text" id="cr" name="cr" value="" autocomplete="off">
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

And the js:

```
function check()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
        if(response!="")
        {
            if(!(confirm('Already added:\n' + response + '\n\nAdd anyway?')))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    }
    var cr = document.getElementById('cr').value;
    xmlhttp.open("GET","check.php?q=" + cr);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

If I keep my confirm prompt alone, the `return false` works as it should and stops the submit. Nested in the `xmlhttp.open` on the other hand, it submits whatever I answer. Any good or bad ideas are appreciated!

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous method! The function is finished before the call comes back.

Comment: it's asynchronous. as soon as you call .send(), your check function returns ANWYAYS. it won't wait for the ajax response to come back

Comment: So no ways do do it? Taking the xmlhttp out in its own function with a callback to confirm if found?

Comment: Using the submit() function in js instead of return I got it working. Thanks for initial guiding!